# Get the Number of Unanswered calls from Windows Phone App

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to get the number of unanswered calls while the app is on , from my Windows Phone app ? I only want to get the count. Any phone number or person details are not needed. If it is possible How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.  As per answer from an MVP:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/7ba65ddf-13ab-4bda-b93f-e1e88fd5d470/